# implement the iOS round button in Android

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android, android-button

I am trying to create the iOS round button in Android. As you may know, Android buttons have grey background while the iOS round button has a clear background. I should use styles and themes to achieve this.

However, I do not know how to piece things together. Could anyone please give some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for styles or themes. The trick with buttons on Android is to use a separate image for each state, and then combine them all with a selector xml. You can put something like this in your drawable directory and reference it like an image:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_small_normal" />
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_small_normal_disable" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_small_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_small_selected" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_small_normal" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_small_normal_disable_focused" />
  <item
     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_small_normal_disable" />
</selector>
```

Then just set the button background to this drawable. See [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Shawn..I would like to access the images to correspond with the button states..any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks Shawn, this will suffice!!